# NetSuite: How to Reference Custom Fields in Grouped Invoices Using Advanced PDF/HTML Templates

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

We are using NetSuite's Advanced PDF Template for Grouped Invoices to print groups of invoices and need to include an existing custom field (custbody_subscription_name from the invoice header) on each invoice row in the invoice group.

[image]

We can add the custom field to the view in the Invoice Group app, but how do we reference the customized field in the PDF template? The template appears to use a hardcoded name 'groupedinvoices_summary' to refer to each group of invoices, but it's unclear how to reference a custom field. Here's a snippet of our customized HTML template with our 'custbody_subscription_name' custom field:

```html
<table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><#list groupedinvoices_summary as invoice><#if invoice_index==0>
<thead>
<tr style="background-color: #d3d3d3;">
<td align="center" colspan="4" style="font-weight: bold;border-left: 1px solid; border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid ">${invoice.custbody_subscription_name@label}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="4" style="font-weight: bold;border-left: 1px solid; border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid ">${invoice.invoicenum@label}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3" style="font-weight: bold;border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid ">${invoice.itemtotal@label}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3" style="font-weight: bold;border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid ">${invoice.discounttotal@label}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3" style="font-weight: bold;border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid ">${invoice.trantaxtotal@label}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3" style="font-weight: bold;border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid ">${invoice.shippingcharge@label}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3" style="font-weight: bold;border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid ">${invoice.handlingcharge@label}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3" style="font-weight: bold;border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid ">${invoice.fxamount@label}</td>
</tr>
</thead>
</#if><tr>
<td align="left" colspan="4" style="color: #333333;border-left: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid">${invoice.custbody_subscription_name}</td>
<td align="left" colspan="4" style="color: #333333;border-left: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid">${invoice.invoicenum}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid">${invoice.itemtotal}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid">${invoice.discounttotal}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid">${invoice.trantaxtotal}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid">${invoice.shippingcharge}</td>
<td align="center" colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid">${invoice.handlingcharge}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid">${invoice.fxamount}</td>
</tr>
</#list></table>
```

UPDATE #1: After trying various approaches the main issue is that, apparently, only fields in the default views can be referenced. How do we work around this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add data to an Advanced PDF template in SuiteScript using the TemplateRenderer.addCustomDataSource() method.

```
var invoiceGroupInvoiceReportRows = { groupedinvoices_summary: [<your data>] };
var invoiceDetailReportRows = { invoice_details: [<your data>] };
xmlReport.addCustomDataSource({
    format: render.DataSource.OBJECT,
    alias: 'results',
    data: invoiceGroupInvoiceReportRows
});
```

Then reference that data in the report XML like this:

```
results.groupedinvoices_summary
```

Refer to Suite Answers [82586](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/82586/kw/82586), [49339](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49339/kw/49339), and [44622](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44622) for more information/

Answer (score 1):

You can create an "Other Record Field" for Invoice Group type to source some fields from the Subsidiary and Customer records.